# Function Add Month in informix

Tags: sql, informix

I need a function that adds the current date to 1 month.
I do so:

```
let _date =     MDY(MONTH(current_date)+1, DAY(current_date), YEAR(current_date));
```

But there is a problem with the months in which the days <31

Comment: Hi Dimitri, you may have to tell us a bit more about what you need, preferably with examples. For example, are you trying to get the same day in the next month? What should happen on the boundaries like 31st? So, 2015-10-15 --> 2015-11-15? 2015-10-31 --> 2015-12-01? Please tell us your requirement.

Comment: Here's what you get
2015-10-15 --> 2015-11-15
2015-01-31 --> 2015-02-28

Comment: On the borders of the month, it should be the last day of the month. February 28, April 30. If the next month is not 31 numbers, then select the last day of the month

Comment: Did you try the funcion add_months() ?  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1531.htm?lang=en

Comment: I have a version of Informix 11.70

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check whether it works in your version, but you should get the result you want if you have a sufficiently modern version of Informix (11.70.FC5 or later, or version 12.10.FC1 or later) and you use DATETIME arithmetic.

```
LET next_month = EXTEND(current_date, YEAR TO DAY) + 1 UNITS MONTH
```

Older versions of Informix will baulk if the day is out of range for the target month.

---

Testing on a 12.10 server, I used this SQL:

```
create table dl (dv date not null primary key);
insert into dl values('2012-01-28');
insert into dl values('2012-01-29');
insert into dl values('2012-01-30');
insert into dl values('2012-01-31');
insert into dl values('2012-02-01');

SELECT dv, EXTEND(dv, YEAR TO DAY) + 1 UNITS MONTH FROM dl;
```

Given that I run with `DBDATE=Y4MD-` set in my environment, the output was:

```
2012-01-28    2012-02-28
2012-01-29    2012-02-29
2012-01-30    2012-02-29
2012-01-31    2012-02-29
2012-02-01    2012-03-01
```

This was testing with a 12.10.FC5 version.  I can confirm that with 11.70.FC4 I get an error on the addition of 1 month to 2012-01-30.  I reviewed the code while writing this addendum to my answer; it was fixed in March 2012 for an 11.70 fixpack.  AFAICT, the first fix pack after the check in was 11.70.FC5.  Since you have 11.70.FC3, the old behaviour — a deliberate design decision from circa 1990, not a bug per se — was still in the product.

Comment: I have Informix Server Version 11.70.FC3
Сhecking
select EXTEND(DATE('31/01/2015'), YEAR TO DAY) + 1 UNITS MONTH from dual
SQL Error (-1267): The result of a datetime computation is out of range.

Comment: @Dmitriy: Apologies for the delay.  I've checked the code base and updated my answer.  If you have 11.70.FC5 or later, or any 12.10 version, you should be OK.  Otherwise, most probably not — and there isn't a simple workaround.  And I see from your comment you have 11.70.FC3; that is too old to have the fix in place.